# How do I multiselect options into an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to put multiple values into an array with Javascript. I only see jquery solutions.. which does not work with my existing code. this is my code block i am having trouble with..

```
    var c = new Array();
      var cat_ = _("cat_");
     for(i=0;i<cat_.options.length;i++){
        c.push(cat_.options[i].value);
    }

    alert(c);
```

this works to load ALL the options into the array.... i am only looking for *selected* items. As i said... i am not looking for a jquery solution. The rest of the codeblock is Javascript.
 many thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `_("cat_")` "pure JavaScript"? And what does it even do?

Comment: Please provide context... This could help, too: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-select.phtml

Comment: Read  ...... document.getElementById("cat");

Comment: Uh, add an if statement inside the for loop.  `if (currentItem is selected) pushToArray;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had a `<select>` element with multiple selected options, and you wanted to get an array of the selected option elements, or an array of the values of the selected elements, you could do this like below:

```js
function pick() {
  var selected = document.getElementById('sel').selectedOptions;
  var selectedArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(selected);
  alert(selectedArray);
  var selectedValues = selectedArray.map(function(o) { return o.value; });
  alert(selectedValues);
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" size="6" multiple>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<button onclick="pick()">Pick!</button>
```